# How to connect muliple DatagramSocket and send messages

Tags: java, udp, multicast, datagram

Say I have a client that can listen to messages on multicast on the following address:

```
127.0.0.1:1231
127.0.0.2:1232
127.0.0.3:1233
127.0.0.4:1234
```

Currently, what I'm doing is sending messages on `127.0.0.1:1231` which the client can process fine.

But I want to be able to send messages through the other IPs as well (and even take it up a notch by sending messages simultaneously on different addresses).

My approach is just to create 4 `DatagramSockets` and put them in a list. Then in a loop, I'll randomly pick a `DatagramSocket`, connect and send the message.

Is there a better/smarter approach to doing this?

Comment: There is no [tag:nio] here.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can send to all these addresses with a single socket. Keep it open for the life of the process; don't bind it; and don't connect it: put the target address into the `DatagramPacket` each time.